# Convert String to date and get Datepart

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion, string-parsing

I have a string column which has datetime values in this format (Tue Nov 8 06:14:57 GMT 2016). How can I get the date part of this values? like.

```
SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE, 'Tue Nov 8 06:14:57 GMT 2016') as 'Minute'
SELECT DATEPART(Day, 'Tue Nov 8 06:14:57 GMT 2016') as 'Day'
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance,
Ziad

Comment: It is a very bad idea to store a date in a culture specific format and it is even worse to use a language specific format... Can you be sure, that this will always run on a system with default language is english? Otherwise you'd have to map the name parts yourself...

Comment: The root of the problem is "I have a string column which has datetime values". Since this is stored in the wrong datatype you are now realizing why datatype is so important.

Comment: I know that but I got the data in csv file and it has this stupid format and I have need to fix it somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way to get a date from your strange string

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (YourStrangeDate VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @table VALUES('Tue Nov 8 06:14:57 GMT 2016');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourStrangeDate,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Casted
    FROM @table 
)
SELECT
CAST(
             Casted.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(2)') --third part = "8" 
     + ' ' + Casted.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(3)') --second part = "Nov"
     + ' ' + Casted.value('/x[6]','nvarchar(4)') --6th part = "2016"
     + ' ' + Casted.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(8)') --4th part = Time
     AS DATETIME)
FROM Splitted;
```

**Attention** The implicit `CAST()` to `DATETIME` will rely on your system's settings. This will fail, if your month's abbreviation is not the one your system expects (e.g. "Dec" is "Dez" on a german system).

From your comment I take, that this is a one time action (CSV import). You might specify `SET LANGUAGE English;` into the first line to be sure...

With a real date you can continue using the related functions such as `DATEPART()`

### Hint

Always use the appropriate type to store your data! You should use this to repair your data, not for any muddy output...

Comment: Such a nice script. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the date 9 and/or 10 symbol will belong to day, and 1 or 2 symbols after first `:` sign will be minute. So, you can get them with this query

```
    declare @x varchar(50) = 'Tue Nov 8 06:14:57 GMT 2016'
    select [Day] = cast(substring(@x, 9, 2) as int)
           , 'Minute' = replace(substring(@x, charindex(':', @x) + 1, 2), ':', '')
```

Comment: I like this plain and pragmatic approach (+1 from my side), but I see some troubles connected to the *`and so on`* :-D...